# Only run SQL Query if there are multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table similar to the below - OrderStatusId is the PK on the table.  StatusId is a FK to the Reference Table that contains all the possible statuses.  CustomerId is a FK to the Customer Details table

```
OrderStatusId StatusId CustomerId DateModified
1               1          1        05/09/2017
2               1          1        06/09/2017
3               2          1        07/09/2017
4               1          2        07/09/2017
```

What I want to do is run this query below to select the most recent Modified Date for that Customer for Status ID = 1.  However, I only want to run this query if there is a count greater than 1 for the StatusId = 1 for that customer.  So in my sample table above I would expect 06/09/2017 returned for CustomerId 1 but nothing to be returned for CustomerId 2.  I tried a Having count(*) > 1 clause but could not get it working correctly.

```
SELECT TOP(1) os.DateModified AS LastModifiedDateForm
FROM [myTable].[OrderStatus] os WHERE os.CustomerId = 1 AND os.StatusID = 1 
ORDER BY os.DateModified DESC
```

Answer (score 4):

can you just use MAX instead of top 1?  or are you returning more columns?

```
SELECT MAX(os.DateModified) AS LastModifiedDateForm
FROM   [myTable].[OrderStatus] os
WHERE  os.CustomerId = 1
       AND os.StatusID = 1
GROUP BY CustomerId,
         StatusId
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: this is exactly what I needed - cheers.  Will mark as accepted once time limit lets me accept

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are after the maximum date per customer, only if they have more than one date?

```
select max(os.DateModified) AS LastModifiedDateForm
from [myTable].[OrderStatus] os
group by os.CustomerId
having count(1) > 1
```

This will only give you data for customer with id 1, in the current situation, or every other customer id that has more than 1 row for some other sample data.

Answer (score 0):

another approach using `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
with firstonly as (
    select CustomerId, DateModified, ROW_NUMBER() over (partiton by CustomerId order by DateModified desc) rownumDesc, ROW_NUMBER() over (partiton by CustomerId order by DateModified) rownumAsc
    FROM [myTable].[OrderStatus] os WHERE os.CustomerId = 1 AND os.StatusID = 1 
)
select * 
from firstonly 
where rownumDesc = 1
    and rownumAsc != 1
;
```

works for all customers at once

Comment: How would this omit those who have just one row with a status of 1?